# Consuming WebApi Self Host over SSL/TLS

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

I have a WebApi self hosted console server over SSL.

The server takes care of creating the SSL certificates, adding them to the certificate store and binds the certificate to the port using netsh all on the fly.

The server has a simple controller that returns the string "Hello World" through HTTP GET.

[image: Browser is able to access the server]

I can access it through the browser without any problems and I am quite certain there is nothing wrong with the server code so I am only going to post the troubled client code here.

```
private static string url = @"https://localhost:4443/WebApi/Service/HelloWorld;

private static async Task GetHelloWorldRequest(string url)
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(GetSSLHandler()))
        {
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(url);

            await httpClient
                .SendAsync(request)
                .ContinueWith((response)
                =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ProcessResponse(response);
                    }
                    catch (AggregateException agException)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Error getting response: " + agException.Message);
                    }
                }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

    private static void ProcessResponse(Task<HttpResponseMessage> response)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    }

    private static void ProcessResponseHeaders(Task<HttpResponseMessage> response)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(response.Result.Headers.ToString());
    }

private static WebRequestHandler GetSSLHandler()
    {
        WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
        X509Certificate2 certificate = GetMyX509Certificate();
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
        return handler;
    }
```

Now in my main routine I simply call this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Response headers:");
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
Task task = GetHelloWorldRequest(url);
task.Wait();
```

Now my problem is if I try to read the response content which should give me "Hello World" it gives me an empty string instead.

So I tried looking at the response headers and this is what I get:

[image: Response headers]

It seems to be it is going through the negotiation phase and I don't know what to do from here.

Please advice. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

Sorry the problem is with the server code. Simply uncomment the section calling httpBinding.ConfigureTransportBindingElement.

```
class SslHttpsSelfHostConfiguration : HttpSelfHostConfiguration
{
  public SslHttpsSelfHostConfiguration(string baseAddress) : base(baseAddress) { }
  public SslHttpsSelfHostConfiguration(Uri baseAddress) : base(baseAddress) { }

  protected override BindingParameterCollection OnConfigureBinding(HttpBinding httpBinding)
  {
    httpBinding.Security.Mode = HttpBindingSecurityMode.Transport;
    /*
    httpBinding.ConfigureTransportBindingElement = (element =>
      element.AuthenticationScheme =
      AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate);
    */
    return base.OnConfigureBinding(httpBinding);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try running this:

```
var client = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:4443/")
};
var result = await client.GetAsync("WebApi/Service/HelloWorld").ConfigureAwait(false);
var data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
return data;
```

as your Request task.

And try changing the

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

to

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Comment: @schatchz, sorry but I'm still getting an empty string instead of "Hello World"

Comment: That's really weird... I've done this with ssl servers and it worked..
Can you please add your server code? Specifically, how you implement the method?

Comment: @schlatchz, sorry I found the problem is in my server code. Your code has been most valuable. I will update it in my question.